# I get this error: Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'Value' yet Value has a value. Why?

Tags: function, asp-classic, vbscript

I am receiving the error in the title within the following function:

```
function ExtractOptions(value)
  dim index

  index = InStr(1, value, ":")
  ExtractOptions = CStr(Mid(value, index + 1, value.length - 1))

end function
```

However, when I place a watch on "value" it shows that it contains a string value when used in the ExtractOptions assignment statement which is where the error occurs.

Here is the calling code in case it provides any insight:

```
<%
  if not isnumeric(dictCart(Key)) then 
%>
  <TR>
    <TD id="cart_item_options" class=<%=TextCCSStyle%> ALIGN="left"><%= ExtractOptions(dictCart(Key)) %></TD>
  </TR>    
<% end if %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your call to `value.length`.

Instead, try the `Len` function, like this:

```
ExtractOptions = CStr(Mid(value, index + 1, Len(value) - 1))
```